# Como recorrer un Json con Array

Tags: java, android-studio, json, gson

Buenas estoy teniendo problemas para recorrer un json con array o eso creo, os dejo  el codigo json:

```
 {
    "username": "Pepiko",
    "platform": "pc",
    "stats": {
        "kills_solo": 1,
        "placetop1_solo": 0,
        "placetop10_solo": 1,
        "placetop25_solo": 1
    },
    "totals": {
        "kills": 13,
        "wins": 0,
        "kd": 0.41
    }
}
```

El problema lo tengo para poder acceder por ejemplo a "stats" o "totals". Cuando lanzo el emulador, me arroja el siguiente Error:

**com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT at line 1 column 148 path $.stats**

Creo que dice que esta esperando un Array, pero creo que estoy pasando le un objecto. La duda es que no se como puedo sacar un array a partir de un **List<>**

**FichaUsuario.java**

```
public class FichaUsuario {
         public String username;
         public String platform;
         public List<stats> stats;
}
```

**stats.java**

```
public class stats {
    public int kills_solo;
    public int placetop1_solo;
    public int placetop10_solo;
}
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
try {
    Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
    if( response.isSuccessful() ){
        String jsonResponder = response.body().string();

        Log.d("Testeo", jsonResponder);
        Gson gson = new Gson(); // Carga Libreria Gson
        FichaUsuario fichaUsuario = gson.fromJson(jsonResponder, FichaUsuario.class);
        Log.d("Testeo", fichaUsuario.username + fichaUsuario.platform + fichaUsuario.stats.placetop10_solo);

    }else{
        Log.d("ERROR", response.body().string());
    }
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

¿Que es lo que estoy haciendo mal?, ¿Que pasos debo seguir para mostrar los atributos de stats del json?. Recuedo que trabajo con la libreria Gson, Gracias de Antemano Comunidad.

P.D. Dejo el mensaje completo del Error que me tira.

```
     com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT at line 1 column 148 path $.stats
            at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:226)
            at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:927)
            at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:892)
            at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:841)
            at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:813)
            at 
com.test.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:67)
            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6294)
            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:24770)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:790)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
         Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT at line 1 column 148 path $.stats
            at com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader.beginArray(JsonReader.java:350)
            at com.google.gson.internal.bind.CollectionTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(CollectionTypeAdapterFactory.java:80)
            at com.google.gson.internal.bind.CollectionTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(CollectionTypeAdapterFactory.java:61)
            at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$1.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:131)
            at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:222)
            at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:927) 
            at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:892) 
            at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:841) 
            at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:813) 
            at 
com.test.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:67) 
            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6294) 
            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:24770) 
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:790) 
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164) 
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494) 
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
            at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438) 
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
"stats": {
    "kills_solo": 1,
    "placetop1_solo": 0,
    "placetop10_solo": 1,
    "placetop25_solo": 1
},
```

La cuestión es que esto no es para nada un array (o lista), es un objeto. Los arrays se marcan con corchetes, aunque solo tengan un elemento, o ninguno. Para que esto fuera un array, debería ser:

```
"stats": [{
    "kills_solo": 1,
    "placetop1_solo": 0,
    "placetop10_solo": 1,
    "placetop25_solo": 1
}],
```

Así que lo que tienes que hacer:

```
public class FichaUsuario {
     public String username;
     public String platform;
     public stats stats;
}
```

En otro orden de cosas, el estándar es que los nombres de clases siempre empiecen por mayúsculas.